# Problems creating regex validation for alphanumeric and some special characters

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

I'm trying to write a validation function for a comment section in a form. I want to allow numbers, letters, single quotes, $, &, ?, and ! .

This is what I currently have, but it doesn't allow for the $, &, ?, or !.

```
function verifyAlphaNum ($testString) {         

return (preg_match ("/^([[:alnum:]]|-|\.| |')+$/", $testString));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function verifyField ($testString) {

    return (preg_match ("/^[[:alnum:].\?!$&' ]+$/", $testString));
}
```

With the class, you accept numbers, letters, dot, ?, !, &, $, single quotes and spaces.